# youTube data API V3 - search return Error 400 when PublishedAfter is used

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am running a search by keyword from a java project, exactly like in the example -

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword

It works great, but when I add to the example the PublishedAfter option
**search.setPublishedAfter(myDateTime);**

it returns error 400 message": "Bad Request"

```
  YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

  String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
  search.setKey(apiKey);
  search.setQ(queryTerm);
  search.setPublishedAfter(myDateTime) // the code works when removing this line

  search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
  search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

  SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
  List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
```

I want to use the setPublishedAfter option

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the client is encoding the date string, when the API expects the characters to be normal, for example publishedAfter=2014-05-28T14%3A10%3A40%2B00%3A00Z is what it is sending, but if you take the api link, this works //www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCZaT_X_mc0BI-djXOlfhqWQ&maxResults=50&videoSyndicated=true&part=id%2Csnippet&key=YOUR_API_KEY&alt=json&type=video&order=date&publishedAfter=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

I'm not sure why the client is doing this. I'm working in python btw.

Comment: Ah, I've noticed that my datetime is sending +00:00 hour and min offset information, which I think needs to be removed. The time component should just be T00:00:00Z

Comment: Are you using the forMine parameter? If I use forMine AND publishedAfter I get a 400 error (even using the YouTube API Explorer, see https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252Csnippet&forMine=true&publishedAfter=2014-01-01T00%253A00%253A00Z&q=quadcopter&type=video&_h=11& gives 'The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions'). Also see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6666

Comment: not using forMine. To solve the problem I used the simple rest API instead of the java api.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube api v3 says that "*The publishedAfter parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created after the specified time. The value is an RFC 3339 formatted date-time value (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)*" Therefore, your problem is most likely to because of your date format. Look at your "myDateTime" object. Mistake should be near to it. Also look at my code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentDateOfAmerica=cal.getTime();
cal.set(12, cal.get(12)-1);
Date dateOneMinuteBefore=cal.getTime();
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(dateOneMinuteBefore);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(currentDateOfAmerica);

search.setPublishedAfter(dt1);
search.setPublishedBefore(dt2);
```

This code segment sets searching video which are uploaded between now and one minute ago

Comment: This is how I creat myDateTime:                                 DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*60*60);                                                        You see a problem with that?

Comment: I cannot see the problem now. Change code your code according to mine code. If error continues, maybe there is another problem. However it should be the format

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with fields part. Most likely publishedafter is not described in fields part you suggested.

Just comment out `setFields`, should work.

Comment: try taking out id from list. YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("snippet");